# Alternative to assigning multiple Tables to Users in SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'm making an inventory system for a hospital that will contain data about biological samples. I'm using SQLite as a database. This system should ideally be used for all sorts of studies.

Since each study and each user will have different fields, and different numbers of fields they'd require for their respective studies, I wanted to make these fields user-configurable rather than static. One way I thought of adding this functionality is allowing the user to create a "study", which, internally will create an SQL table specifically for that study. Users might have multiple studies, and thus might have multiple entire *tables* associated with their accounts.

How might I go about accomplishing this? I've attached screenshots below of what, ultimately, I want to show to the user.

Let's say the user is part of 3 different studies, which appear on their homepage. They click on Study 1 and see:
[image: Example structure for study 1]

Similarly, for Studies 2 and 3:
[image: Example structures for studies 2 and 3]

Multiple users might be part of multiple studies. This I know I can accomplish with an intermediate many-many relationship.

My main question is, how can I have different numbers of fields for different studies? The only way I can come up with right now is to create an SQL Table every time a user creates a new study. I understand this isn't best practice, however. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this OK? I feel like it's a taboo.

Taboo no, but contrary to normalisation and good use of the relational aspect of a relational database.

When you have a varying list of something belonging to something else then two tables with a suitable relationship can cope.

**In short there is, what many would say, a better way:-**

You mention a Study having a varying number of fields, so 2 tables **study** and **field**, the field can have a many to 1 relationship with the study. So a study could then have 0-many fields (obviously an empty study would be of little use).

So starting off you could have:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS study (
    studyid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    studyname TEXT, 
    studystartdate TEXT, 
    studyenddate TEXT
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS field (
    fieldid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    owningstudy INTEGER REFERENCES study(studyid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    fieldtext TEXT
);
```

- the **owningstudy** relating to the study that it belongs to. A field can only relate to 1 study but a study can have many fields relating to it.

You mention Users, so a table for the users e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user (
    userid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username TEXT,
    userdob TEXT
);
```

You mention samples related to a field and also to a user and that how many samples per user per field (which belongs to a study) is variable. In database terms a many-many relationship exists.

A many-many relationship is typically (only?) afforded by an intermediate table (with various names such as associative table, mapping table, reference table ....). Such a table has at least two columns one to relate to one of the tables, the other column to relate to the other table. The primary key is typically a composite of both columns. In short you could have:-

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sample (
    fieldidmap INTEGER REFERENCES field(fieldid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    useridmap INTEGER REFERENCES user(userid) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    reading REAL,
    PRIMARY KEY (useridmap,fieldidmap)
);
```

- Note that `REFERENCES` is used to add a constrain (rule) that prevents invalid values (orphans). It is not compulsory to have such constraints (but recommended).
- the `CASCADES` cascade an action upon the parent (the referenced table) to the children (owner).
- this expands upon the pure mapping/relationship by also including a column for the reading associated with the sample.

So using the above you could add some data, such as:-

```
INSERT INTO study VALUES 
    (100,'A','2023-01-01','2023-01-31')
    ,(101,'B','2023-02-01','2023-02-28')
    ,(102,'C','2023-03-01','2023-03-31')
;
INSERT INTO field VALUES
    (500,100,'field1')
    ,(501,100,'field2')
    ,(502,100,'field3')
    ,(503,101,'field1')
    ,(504,102,'field1')
    ,(505,102,'field2')
    ,(506,102,'field3')
    ,(507,102,'field4')
;
INSERT INTO user VALUES
    (800,'Fred','2000-01-01'),
    (801,'Jane','1998-09-18'),
    (802,'Mary','1999-10-11'),
    (803,'Sue','2001-11-10'),
    (804,'Tom','1996-13-03')
;
INSERT INTO sample VALUES
    (500,800,11.11),(500,803,22.22)
    ,(501,803,33.33)
    ,(502,800,44.44),(502,804,55.55),(502,802,66.66)
    ,(503,804,77.77),(503,803,88.88)
    ,(505,802,99.99),(505,801,12.12),(505,804,13.13)
    ,(506,800,14.14),(506,801,15.15),(506,802,16.16),(506,803,17.17),(506,804,18.18)
    ,(507,803,19.19)
;
```

To take the very fist value (500,800,11.11). This

- maps to the row in the field table with a fieldid value of 500 (the very first with **field1**), this implicitly relkates to the owningstudy i.e. the study with the name **A**, and
- also to the user who has a user of 800, and
- the reading value is 11.11

and so on.

Now consider, as an example, the following SELECT query:-

```
SELECT study.*, field.fieldtext,user.username,user.userdob,sample.reading
FROM study
    JOIN field ON field.owningstudy = study.studyid
    JOIN sample ON sample.fieldidmap = field.fieldid
    JOIN user ON user.userid = sample.useridmap
;
```

The result being (with the data inserted as above) :-

```
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field1  Fred    2000-01-01  11.11
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field1  Sue 2001-11-10  22.22
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field2  Sue 2001-11-10  33.33
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field3  Fred    2000-01-01  44.44
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field3  Tom 1996-13-03  55.55
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field3  Mary    1999-10-11  66.66
101 B   2023-02-01  2023-02-28  field1  Tom 1996-13-03  77.77
101 B   2023-02-01  2023-02-28  field1  Sue 2001-11-10  88.88
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field2  Mary    1999-10-11  99.99
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field2  Jane    1998-09-18  12.12
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field2  Tom 1996-13-03  13.13
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Fred    2000-01-01  14.14
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Jane    1998-09-18  15.15
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Mary    1999-10-11  16.16
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Sue 2001-11-10  17.17
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Tom 1996-13-03  18.18
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field4  Sue 2001-11-10  19.19
```

- Study **A** has 6 samples 2 for Fred (field1 and field 3), 2 for Sue (field1 and field2) 1 for Tom (field3) and 1 for Mary (field3).
- Study **B**  has 2 samples ....
- Study **C** has 9 samples

From User POV (aka sorted by Userid using `ORDER BY user.userid, study.studyid`) then the **EXACT** same data yields:-

```
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field1  Fred    2000-01-01  11.11
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field3  Fred    2000-01-01  44.44
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Fred    2000-01-01  14.14
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field2  Jane    1998-09-18  12.12
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Jane    1998-09-18  15.15
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field3  Mary    1999-10-11  66.66
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field2  Mary    1999-10-11  99.99
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Mary    1999-10-11  16.16
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field1  Sue 2001-11-10  22.22
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field2  Sue 2001-11-10  33.33
101 B   2023-02-01  2023-02-28  field1  Sue 2001-11-10  88.88
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Sue 2001-11-10  17.17
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field4  Sue 2001-11-10  19.19
100 A   2023-01-01  2023-01-31  field3  Tom 1996-13-03  55.55
101 B   2023-02-01  2023-02-28  field1  Tom 1996-13-03  77.77
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field2  Tom 1996-13-03  13.13
102 C   2023-03-01  2023-03-31  field3  Tom 1996-13-03  18.18
```

- e.g. Fred has submitted 3 samples for 2 for study **A** and 1 for study **C** (obviously 0 for study **B**)

Comment: I apologize for not making my question clear enough, but what I wanted for this database was for each study to have varying titles and *numbers* of fields; I've edited my question, and hopefully made it more clear. Again, I apologize for the confusion, and thank you for your answer nonetheless. It helped solidify a lot of SQL concepts for me!

Comment: @AyaanPathan in the above the number of fields per study are variable (e.g. study A has 3 fields,  B has 1 and C has 4). For varying titles you just apply the same concept.